# Comparing textbox.text to char c#

Tags: c#, char, compare

Just wondering if there is a way that I can compare the text in my textbox to a char without making a string to do it? My way seems a bit inefficient. It is 'a[i].Text' i am comparing to 'number', thanks in advance if you can help.

```
private void a1calculate(char number)
{
    bool plausible = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {                
        string numberr = Convert.ToString(number);
        var a = hello('a');
        if (a[i].Text == numberr) { plausible = false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "number" a `char`? Unless it explicitly represents the *codepoint for a single character* (in which case it is a "digit"), it should be an integer or other similar suitable type.

Comment: What are example values of `number` and `hello('a')`?

Comment: number would be 1-9 and hello('a') would return var a = new[] { a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9};
i'm just toying around with making a sudoku solver as an out of school project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get one `char` from the `string` using indexer `[]` syntax. Additional `string.Length` check will give you what you need.

```
if (a[i].Text.Length == 1 && a[i].Text[0] == number) { plausible = false; }
```

Comment: Why are we checking that the text length is 1? Surely it would be 1 if it equals number?

Comment: No, because `a[i].Text[0]` takes only first `char` from your `string TextBox.Text` property, and that first char is being compared with your char. It does not says anything about other characters from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be this:

```
if(a[i].Text[0] == number) ...
```

However, this sample does an index lookup. How performant that is (in comparison to a conversion) is something you'll have to test.